# Sound Cloud and FLASH

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, api, audio, soundcloud

I'm having troubles with connecting flash and sound cloud api so i would really appriciate if someone with bigger experience could help me out.

1. Is it possible to stream an audio file through flash without
   embedding the sc player? What i mean is accessing the audio file
   without any redirects plus granting access through crossdomain.xml.
2. Is there an up to date documentation how to autenticate an
   application, how to get tokens and everything necessary?
3. Are there any sample solutions or tutorials in flash wich is up to date and really works (what i found was pretty much outdated)?

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Regards:
Gabe

Comment: Unfortunately our AS3 SDK is not officially supported. It's one of the less used SDKs and not maintained by SoundCloud. We do host a crossdomain.xml file on api.soundcloud.com:

http://api.soundcloud.com/crossdomain.xml

In terms of documentation and examples however, they are sorely lacking. Sorry about that. If you have any improvements you could make, feel free to contact the maintainer of the project or submit a pull request on Github!

I realize this isn't the most helpful answer. Hopefully someone in the SO community who's more familiar with Flash / AS can help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you know if it is possible to reach the audio stream directly or it is only accesible through redirects?

Comment: Because the final URI contains a time-limited access key, it is only available through a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

### Point 2) How to authenticate with Flash?

If you are building a flash web application, you could use the Javascript SDK to authenticate, then pass the access token back to the flash app via the flash external interface.

There's tons of information on how to authenticate in Javascript. One great walkthrough is on codecademy: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-intermediate-en-txGOj/0/1